# Array/String lastIndexOf inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Code is self describing

```
[3, 1, 3].lastIndexOf(3)
2
[3, 1, 3].lastIndexOf(3, undefined)
0 // wtf?

//ok, lets compare with string

'313'.lastIndexOf(3)
2
'313'.lastIndexOf(3, undefined)
2 //wow!
```

Comment: `Number(undefined)` => `NaN`; `[3,1,3].lastIndexOf(3, NaN);` => `0`. So I assume it must be a deliberate error in the event of a failure in parsing the 'from-index,' why it apparently evaluates to `0` (the 'from-index', rather than the result) I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different algorithms in the spec.

The [Array version](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.lastindexof) performs `ToInteger()` on its second parameter if one was provided, which substitutes `0` for `NaN`.

> 6. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be len-1.

---

The [String version](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.lastindexof) uses `ToNumber()` on its second parameter irrespective of whether or not one was provided, which will return `NaN` without a substitute, so the algorithm manually substitutes `Infinity` for `NaN`.

> 6. Let numPos be ToNumber(position). (If position is undefined, this step produces the value NaN).
> 7. ReturnIfAbrupt(numPos).
> 8. If numPos is NaN, let pos be +∞; otherwise, let pos be ToInteger(numPos).

---

As to why, we can only guess, but the `Array` version is the newer of the two *(ES5)*, so they must have decided that `NaN` would be better off being replaced with `0`, which makes at least a little sense considering its *falsey* evaluation *(not that it's necessarily relevant)*.

Comment: It could make sense for indexOf method, but not for lastIndexOf.